# Qt qrc resource path doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I would like to show an image within a `QLabel` widget. The image is located in the folder `./images/` relative to the `resource.qrc` file and included like the this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>image.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Now I want to show the image within a `QLabel`:

```
QPixmap pixmap( ":/images/image.png" );
label->setPixmap( pixmap );
```

This don't work. While in debug mode `pixmap = NULL`. I think the qrc path is wrong. With the absolute system path to the image `c:/images/...` it works fine. Any idea?

Comment: have you initialize your resource?

Comment: I think so. in my .pro file it's mentioned as "RESOURCES = resource.qrc"

Comment: you need something like 'Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources);' in your program

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The prefix you've specified is applied to the resource path inside the app. It doesn't apply to the real path of the file. The correct resource should be:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>images/image.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And the resource path will be `:/images/images/image.png`.

You can also specify `prefix="/"` in RCC file and use `://images/image.png` resource path. I think it's more convenient.

Comment: ok, everything is fine. I need to execute qMake after the changes in .pro file. your description was absolutely correct. thanks

Comment: QMake didn't quite do it for me, but a restart of QtCreator did.

Answer (score 6):

If you use an alias in your resource file giving: -

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/images">
    <file alias="image">images/image.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then you can access your image as you are doing with: -

> ":/images/image.png"